# How do I visualize the intersection of spheres in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, visualization

It seems this question has been asked in a few places ([including on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35130336/draws-the-intersecting-volume-of-two-spheres-in-matlab)). I recently came across the need for this when visualizing results of a [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) problem.

In almost every case, the answer directs the inquiry to look at [Wolfram for the math](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Sphere-SphereIntersection.html) but excludes any code. The math really is a great reference, but if I'm asking a question on programming, some code might help as well. (It certainly is also appreciated when answers to a code question avoid pithy comments like "writing the code is trivial").

So how can one visualize the intersection of spheres in MATLAB? I have a simple solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a small script to do just this. Feel free to make suggestions and edits. It works by checking if the surface of each sphere falls within the volume of all of the other spheres.

For sphere intersection, it's better (but slower) to use a larger number of faces in the `sphere()` function call. This should give denser results in the visualization. For the sphere-alone visualization, a smaller number (~50) should suffice. See the comments for how to visualize each.

```
close all
clear
clc

% centers   : 3 x N matrix of [X;Y;Z] coordinates
% dist      : 1 x N vector of sphere radii

%% Plot spheres (fewer faces)
figure, hold on % One figure to rule them all
[x,y,z] = sphere(50); % 50x50-face sphere
for i = 1 : size(centers,2)
    h = surfl(dist(i) * x + centers(1,i), dist(i) * y + centers(2,i), dist(i) * z + centers(3,i));
    set(h, 'FaceAlpha', 0.15)
    shading interp
end

%% Plot intersection (more faces)
% Create a 1000x1000-face sphere (bigger number = better visualization)
[x,y,z] = sphere(1000);

% Allocate space
xt = zeros([size(x), size(centers,2)]);
yt = zeros([size(y), size(centers,2)]);
zt = zeros([size(z), size(centers,2)]);
xm = zeros([size(x), size(centers,2), size(centers,2)]);
ym = zeros([size(y), size(centers,2), size(centers,2)]);
zm = zeros([size(z), size(centers,2), size(centers,2)]);

% Calculate each sphere
for i = 1 : size(centers, 2)
    xt(:,:,i) = dist(i) * x + centers(1,i);
    yt(:,:,i) = dist(i) * y + centers(2,i);
    zt(:,:,i) = dist(i) * z + centers(3,i);
end

% Determine whether the points of each sphere fall within another sphere
% Returns booleans
for i = 1 : size(centers, 2)
    [xm(:,:,:,i), ym(:,:,:,i), zm(:,:,:,i)] = insphere(xt, yt, zt, centers(1,i), centers(2,i), centers(3,i), dist(i)+0.001);
end

% Exclude values of x,y,z that don't fall in every sphere
xmsum = sum(xm,4);
ymsum = sum(ym,4);
zmsum = sum(zm,4);
xt(xmsum < size(centers,2)) = 0;
yt(ymsum < size(centers,2)) = 0;
zt(zmsum < size(centers,2)) = 0;

% Plot intersection
for i = 1 : size(centers,2)
    xp = xt(:,:,i);
    yp = yt(:,:,i);
    zp = zt(:,:,i);
    zp(~(xp & yp & zp)) = NaN;
    surf(xt(:,:,i), yt(:,:,i), zp, 'EdgeColor', 'none');
end
```

and here is the `insphere` function

```
function [x_new,y_new,z_new] = insphere(x,y,z, x0, y0, z0, r)
    x_new = (x - x0).^2 + (y - y0).^2 + (z - z0).^2 <= r^2;
    y_new = (x - x0).^2 + (y - y0).^2 + (z - z0).^2 <= r^2;
    z_new = (x - x0).^2 + (y - y0).^2 + (z - z0).^2 <= r^2;
end
```

---

**Sample visualizations**

For the 6 spheres used in these examples, it took an average of 1.934 seconds to run the combined visualization on my laptop.

Intersection of 6 spheres:
[image: Intersection of 6 spheres]

Actual 6 spheres:
[image: not intersection]

Below, I've combined the two so you can see the intersection in the view of the spheres.
[image: both]

For these examples:

```
centers =

   -0.0065   -0.3383   -0.1738   -0.2513   -0.2268   -0.3115
    1.6521   -5.7721   -1.7783   -3.5578   -2.9894   -5.1412
    1.2947   -0.2749    0.6781    0.2438    0.4235   -0.1483

dist =

    5.8871    2.5280    2.7109    1.6833    1.9164    2.1231
```

I hope this helps anyone else who may desire to visualize this effect.

Comment: I'd say your visualization is broken because of the "deletion" of points is too strict and you dont account for small numerical errors.  The rest is amazing.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: What do you mean about the deletion of points being too strict? Could you explain further? It is certainly true that this code requires densely sampled spheres in order to get a good visualization. Otherwise, you're right, points can get left out.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: Ahh I gotcha. Yeah that has to do with the density of the sphere. A sphere with few faces is going to have fewer points, so removing one is going to impact the quality of the visualization (due to the surf function) .The easiest solution is just to increase the number of faces in the sphere

Comment: @marcman no, you are being too strict in cropping points. [See this!](https://i.imgur.com/On3kxmh.png).  In `%% Determine whether the points of each sphere fall within another sphere` add 0.001 to `dist(i)`. Also, I suggest `...,'EdgeColor','none,...'` in surf, and a `camlight` looks nice.

Comment: Good call! I updated the OP to reflect @AnderBiguri's suggestions.