# Finding center point given distance matrix

Tags: matrix, computer-vision, distance, mathematical-optimization, numerical-methods

I have a matrix (really a loaded image) in which every element is a L2 distance from some unknown center point.

Here is a trivial example

```
A = [1.4142  1.0000  1.4142  2.2361]
    [1.0000  0.0000  1.0000  2.0000]
    [1.4142  1.0000  1.4142  2.2361]
```

In this case, the center is obviously at coordinate (1,1) (index A[1,1] in a 0-indexed matrix or 2D array).

However, in the case where my centers are not constrained to be integer indices, it's no longer as obvious. For example, given this matrix `B`, where is my center coordinate?

```
B = [3.0292  1.9612  2.8932  5.8252]
    [1.2292  0.1612  1.0932  4.0252]
    [1.4292  0.3612  1.2932  4.2252]
```

How would you find that the answer in this case is at row 1.034 and column 1.4?

I am aware of the [trilateration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration) solution (having [provided MATLAB code to visualize that in 3D previously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40521806/3427580)), but is there a more efficient way (e.g. one without a matrix inversion)?

This question is sort of language agnostic, as I am looking more for algorithmic help. If you could stick to MATLAB, Python, or C++ though in a solution, that would be great ;-).

Comment: Are the values in A or B exact values or are they noisy ?

Comment: they can be treated as fairly exact

Comment: I'm asking because - as sascha also mentioned - B seems to be 'wrong'. While A is obviously correct, B for your given center point should be something like [[ 1.74044707  1.10867308  1.19547313  1.90503438]
 [ 1.4004128   0.4014424   0.60096256  1.60036121]
 [ 1.70092798  1.04554101  1.13717017  1.86899866]]

Comment: @JulianS.: B is definitely correct--I computed those distances given the true values of (1.034, 1.4). I think the confusion may be that you are assuming the same center? EDIT: Well damn. I had a typo--I changed it to the correct formulation "where my centers are NOT constrained..."

Comment: I think I know what's wrong: the values in B are squared, so you forgot to take sqrt().  It's correct in A but not B.

Comment: @JulianS.: That's entirely possible. Sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

While having no experience with similar tasks, i read some stuff and also tried something.

When unfamiliar with this topic it's hard to grasp it seems and all those resources i found are a bit chaotic.

**Still unclear in regards to theory for me:**

- is the problem as stated above a convex-optimization problem (local-minimum = global-minimum; would mean access to powerful solvers!)

  - there are much more resources about more generic problems (Sensor Network
    Localization), which are non-convex and where extremely complex methods have been developed
- is your trilateration-approach able to exploit > 3 points (trilateration vs. multilateration; at least this code does not seem like it can which means: bad performance with noise!)

**Here some example code with two approaches:**

- **A:** Convex-optimization: SOCP-Relaxation

  - Follows [SECOND-ORDER CONE PROGRAMMING RELAXATION OF SENSOR NETWORK LOCALIZATION](http://xa.yimg.com/kq/groups/13354653/1983214079/name/GetPDFServlet.pdf)
  - Not impressive performance, but should be powerful as approximation for big-data
  - Guaranteed global-optimum for this relaxation!
  - Implemented with [cvxpy](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/index.html)
- **B:** Nonlinear-programming optimization

  - Implemented using scipy.optimize
  - Pretty much perfect in my synthetic experiments; even good results in noisy case; despite the fact we are using numerical-differentiation (automatic-diff hard to use here)

**Some additional remark:**

- Your example B surely has some (pretty bad) noise or some other problem in my opinion, as my approaches are completely off; while especially approach B shines for my synthetic-data (at least that's my impression)

**Code:**

```python
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
from scipy.optimize import minimize
np.random.seed(1)

""" Create noise-free (not anymore!) fake-problem """
real_x = np.random.random(size=2) * 3

M, N = 5, 10
NOISE_DISTS = 0.1
pos = np.array([(i,j) for i in range(M) for j in range(N)])  # ugly -> tile/repeat/stack
real_x_stacked = np.vstack([real_x for i in range(pos.shape[0])])
Y = cdist(pos, real_x[np.newaxis])
Y += np.random.normal(size=Y.shape)*NOISE_DISTS  # Let's add some noise!
print('-----')
print('PROBLEM')
print('-------')
print('real x: ', real_x)
print('dist mat: ', np.round(Y,3).T)

""" Helper """
def cost(x, Y, pos):
    res = np.linalg.norm(pos - x, ord=2, axis=1) - Y.ravel()
    return np.linalg.norm(res, 2)

print('cost with real_x (check vs. noisy): ', cost(real_x, Y, pos))

""" SOLVER SOCP """
def solve_socp_relax(pos, Y):
    x = cvx.Variable(2)
    y = cvx.Variable(pos.shape[0])
    fake_stack = [x for i in range(pos.shape[0])]                     # hacky

    objective = cvx.sum_entries(cvx.norm(y - Y))
    x_stacked = cvx.reshape(cvx.vstack(*fake_stack), pos.shape[0], 2) # hacky
    constraints = [cvx.norm(pos - x_stacked, 2, axis=1) <= y]

    problem = cvx.Problem(cvx.Minimize(objective), constraints)
    problem.solve(solver=cvx.ECOS, verbose=False)
    return x.value.T

""" SOLVER NLP """
def solve_nlp(pos, Y):
    sol = minimize(cost, np.zeros(pos.shape[1]), args=(Y, pos), method='BFGS')
    # print(sol)
    return sol.x

""" TEST """
print('-----')
print('SOLVE')
print('-----')

socp_relax_sol = solve_socp_relax(pos, Y)
print('SOCP RELAX SOL: ', socp_relax_sol)

nlp_sol = solve_nlp(pos, Y)
print('NLP SOL: ', nlp_sol)
```

**Output:**

```
-----
PROBLEM
-------
real x:  [ 1.25106601  2.16097348]
dist mat:  [[ 2.444  1.599  1.348  1.276  2.399  3.026  4.07   4.973  6.118  6.746
   2.143  1.149  0.412  0.766  1.839  2.762  3.851  4.904  5.734  6.958
   2.377  1.432  0.856  1.056  1.973  2.843  3.885  4.95   5.818  6.84
   2.711  2.015  1.689  1.939  2.426  3.358  4.385  5.22   6.076  6.97
   3.422  3.153  2.759  2.81   3.326  4.162  4.734  5.627  6.484  7.336]]
cost with real_x (check vs. noisy):  0.665125233772
-----
SOLVE
-----
SOCP RELAX SOL:  [[ 1.95749275  2.00607253]]
NLP SOL:  [ 1.23560791  2.16756168]
```

**Edit:** Further speedup can be achieved (especially in large-scale) in using nonlinear-least-squares instead of the more general NLP-approach! My results are still the same (as expected if the problem would be convex). Timings between NLP/NLS can look like 9 vs. 0.5 seconds!

**This is my recommended method!**

```python
def solve_nls(pos, Y):
    def res(x, Y, pos):
        return np.linalg.norm(pos - x, ord=2, axis=1) - Y.ravel()
    sol = least_squares(res, np.zeros(pos.shape[1]), args=(Y, pos), method='lm')
    # print(sol)
    return sol.x
```

Especially the second-approach (NLP) will also run for much bigger instances (cvxpy's overhead hurts; that's not a downside of the SOCP-solver which should scale much much better!).

Here some output for `M, N = 500, 1000` with some more noise:

```
-----
PROBLEM
------- 
real x:  [ 12.51066014  21.6097348 ]
dist mat:  [[   24.706    23.573    23.693 ...,  1090.29   1091.216  
1090.817]]
cost with real_x (check vs. noisy):  353.354267797
-----
SOLVE
-----
NLP SOL:  [ 12.51082419  21.60911561]
used:  5.9552763315495625  # SECONDS
```

So in my experiments it works, but i won't give any global-convergence guarantees or reconstruction-guarantees (still missing some theory).

At first i though about using the global optimum of the relaxed-SOCP-problem as initial-point in the NLP-solver, but i did not find any example where this is needed!

Some just-for-fun visuals using:

```python
M, N = 20, 30
NOISE_DISTS = 0.2
...

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(Y.reshape(M, N), cmap='viridis', interpolation='none')
plt.colorbar()
plt.scatter(nlp_sol[1], nlp_sol[0], color='red', s=20)
plt.xlim((0, N))
plt.ylim((0, M))
plt.show()
```

[image]

And some super noisy case (nice performance!):

```python
M, N = 50, 100
NOISE_DISTS = 5

-----
PROBLEM
-------
real x:  [ 12.51066014  21.6097348 ]
dist mat:  [[ 22.329  18.745  27.588 ...,  94.967  80.034  91.206]]
cost with real_x (check vs. noisy):  354.527196716
-----
SOLVE
-----
NLP SOL:  [ 12.44158986  21.50164637]
used:  0.01050068340320306
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a matrix A, where A[i,j] holds the distance from (i,j) to some unknown point (y,x). You could find (y,x) like this:

Square each element of A, to make a matrix B say.
We then want to find (y,x) so

```
(y-i)*(y-i) + (x-j)*(x-j) = B[i,j]
```

Subtracting each equation from the 0,0 equation and rearranging:

```
2*i*y + 2*j*x = B[0,0] + i*i + j*j - B[i,j]
```

This can be solved by linear least squares. Note that since there are 2 unknowns, the matix inversion (better, factorisation) involved will be on a 2x2 matrix and so not time consuming. You could indeed, given just the dimensions of A, work out the required matrix and its inverse analytically.